# Shiny: Restart/break rendering of output when another input is changed

Tags: r, shiny

In my app I've got an `output` depending on many `inputs`. Whenever one of the `inputs` is changed `shiny` refreshes the `output` which takes some long time. The problem occurs when I want to change more than one `input`, because I have to wait X times to get correct `output`. Is there a way to break the refreshing of the `reactive/output` if another `input` was changed?

In this simple example:

`output$distPlot` depends on `input$bins` and `input$col`. Every change in `inputs` takes 3 seconds to refresh a histogram, so when I want to change both of them I have to wait 6 seconds. What I want to do is break existing refreshing if another `input` change was made.

ui

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      selectInput("col","Color",
                  choices = c("green","red","blue"),selected = "green")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

server

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = input$col, border = 'white')
    Sys.sleep(3)
  })
})
```

P.S. `submitButton` is not an option in my case, I'm looking for an option to reset/break rendering

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937698/can-i-let-shiny-wait-for-a-longer-time-for-numericinput-before-updating

Comment: Thanks @HubertL , I found my solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to HubertL I found my answer. I had to create a reactive list with all my dependent `inputs`, and then use `debounce` on it, this way `plot` will change only once (if the time of changing the `inputs` will be less than 3000 mls in this example).

server:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

 shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  inputs_change<-reactive({
    list(input$bins,input$col)
  }) %>% debounce(3000)

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = inputs_change()[[1]] + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = inputs_change()[[2]], border = 'white')
    Sys.sleep(3)
  }) 

})
```

Comment: Don't answer your duplicated question but rather remove it : <  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937698/can-i-let-shiny-wait-for-a-longer-time-for-numericinput-before-updating

Comment: Please upvote the question and answer that you have used to fix your problem. Then remove your question which is a duplicate